# In ExtJS 5.1, I notice ext-all-debug,etc are in ext-5.1.0, where are /resources?

Tags: extjs, extjs5, sencha-cmd

I want to create an ExtJS 5 app by just including the full library.  Not using CMD.  What should my headers look like?  Where is the doc on that?  Instead of the standard ext-all-dev.js I now see /build/ext-all-andbox-debug.  Is that the new ext-all-dev.js?  Also, where are the resources?  Before I would copy over the resource/theme I wanted.  Now I can't find the resources directory.  Nothing in the release notes I can find about this.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter, you probably know what you are doing and you have already read all warnings that discourage you from not using Cmd.

So, css is in `packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/resources/ext-theme-crisp-all.css`

See also this article: http://extjs.eu/single-file-extjs-5-application/

Comment: Saki, are completely comfortable using CMD for projects that you know will list many years and will have to be upgraded through many versions of both Ext and CMD over the years coming?  History has not treated me well over the years with projects that use CMD.  A few have turned into lengthy support incidents with Sencha.

Comment: Well, I also had had troubles with upgrading but there is a last resort approach that always worked whatever else failed. It is 1) generate new (blank) application, 2) delete generated files and copy the app into the directory structure and 3) build. I wouldn't go w/o cmd nowadays.

Comment: I've also had the added complication of SA with some projects upgrades also.  I think you solution is clearly the right one but with SA projects life gets a lot more complicated. I wish I could use gulp, there is so much magic in CMD that it makes me quite nervous.

Comment: Yeah, SA can be a PITA.

Comment: Saki, I've used your post previously to make apps written in 4.2 work and it worked great.  However, in my 5.1 app, the loader refuses to not dynamically load files (even though the app works because the files are really loaded already). I've even tried Ext.Loader ... enabled:false and the load still runs.  any ideas? (besides posting a new question on SO)?

Comment: Hmmm, my observation is that 5.1 is strewn with new bugs not present in 5.0. I cannot say if your problem may be caused by one of them.

Comment: Hi again, if it's not to much to ask, could you take a look at the url https://www.siliconvalley-codecamp.com/extjsapps/tabletapp/indexnomin.html and scan to the very bottom of the main.js file included from view/source.  I think that should disable all the dyn loading but obviously it is not.  I used your call to Ext syncRequire but not really sure what that does

Comment: First, try to run the app with 5.0.1. Or you have to use 5.1 because of new features?

Comment: Saki, no need to look at my url I posted above.  I followed your suggestion and just recreated a new project with CMD and copied the files out of architect and into that.  It was quite fast to get it working as you mentioned.  See you at SenchaCon?